# Objeto em java contem um JSON, quero pegar as informações do JSON e popular meus atributos do objeto

Tags: java, json

É o seguinte, tenho o objeto GPS, ele esta com um json como segue a imagem, quero pegar os dados do campo codigo e do campo nome e colocalos dentro dos atributos do objeto GPS. SEGUE IMMAGEM [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

COmo posso fazer isso ?

Tentei dessa forma, mas sem suceso

```
this.nome = lista.get(acessorio).nome;
this.codigo = lista.get(acessorio).codigo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Já existe uma biblioteca que faz isso, popula os objetos é converte o objeto para json.

Para popular o objeto:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Acessorio gps = gson.fromJson(json, Acessorio.class);
```

Converte o objeto para json:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(objeto);
```

Os objetos **devem** ser um [JavaBeans](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).

Inclua dependência [Maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.8.0%7C) ao seu projeto ou baixe os [Jar's](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/).